# How to use json data in chart.js in an ionic app

Tags: json, charts, ionic2

I would like to implement chart.js, I followed the example [HERE](http://www.discoversdk.com/blog/charts-and-graphs-in-ionic-2-integrating-data-visualization-with-different-libraries), it worked well with a sample array data, but now I want to put live data fetch in json format from my server, I could not get a head way.

this is my html page

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>results</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

 <ion-card >
  <ion-card-header>
    Bar Chart
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content>
    <canvas width="800" height="800" #barCanvas></canvas>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

and my .ts page

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import { LoadingController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions}  from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';



@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-results',
  templateUrl: 'results.html',
})
export class ResultsPage {


  @ViewChild('barCanvas') barCanvas;
  barChart: any;
  selectedOption:any;
  items:any;
  val : any=[];
  val2 : any=[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private http: Http, public loading: LoadingController,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.selectedOption = this.navParams.get('options');



    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let data = {

        option: this.selectedOption

         };

    let loader = this.loading.create({

    content: 'Processing please wait...',

    });

    loader.present().then(() => {

    this.http.post('mydomain/fetch_data.php',data, options)

    .map(res => res.json())

        .subscribe(res => {

         loader.dismiss()

        this.items=res.server_response;

        console.log(this.items);
        this.items.map((item)=>{
          this.val1.push(item.options);
        });
        this.items.map((item)=>{
          this.val2.push(item.result);
        });



        });

        });


    this.showChart();

  }

  showChart(){

           this.barChart = new Chart(this.barCanvas.nativeElement, {

               type: 'bar',
               data: {
                   labels: this.val1,
                   datasets: [{
                       label: '# of Votes',
                       data: this.val2,
                       backgroundColor: [
                           'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                           'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                           'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                           'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)'
                       ],
                       borderColor: [
                           'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                           'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                           'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                           'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'
                       ],
                       borderWidth: 1
                   }]
               },
               options: {
                   scales: {
                       xAxes: [{
                           ticks: {
                               beginAtZero:true
                           }
                       }]
                   }
               }

           });

   }
  }
```

I got json data but to convert it to another array like  labels: ["Red", "Brown", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"], and  data: [11, 15, 22, 4, 6, 2, 3] such that I can use it as val1 and val2 as shown above  is my challenge.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

First you install ng2-charts, and `import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';` to `app/app.module.ts`

> in example.html

```
      <div style="display: block; color:white; responsive: true; 
      maintainAspectRatio: false;">
       <canvas baseChart
       height="350"
       [colors]="chartColors"
       [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
       [data]="doughnutChartData"
       [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
       (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
       (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
      </div>
```

> in example.ts

```
export class ExamplePage {
  doughnutChartLabels: string[] = [];
  doughnutChartData: number[] = [];
  doughnutChartType: string = 'pie';
  checkChart : boolean;
...}
pushItem(){
 #pushed your json data in doughnutChartData
 #end called this fonction in ionViewDidLoad and any methods
}
public chartClicked(e:any):void {
#... 
}

public chartHovered(e:any):void {
#...
}
```

Comment: Must you just post anything even if it does not answer or seem to be relevant to the question, you post is grossly irrelevant to the question. Thank you

Comment: This is Beautiful charts for Angular2 based on Chart.js, [ng2-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-charts) . And title is `How to use json data in chart.js in an ionic app`. My answer is this. Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the question before answering or just the title??